# How to set instance of symfony entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

When I try to insert data into database using `$casesReturn->setOrder($cases['orderid']);`

It gives below error. I've pass the correct order id to the `setOrder` method.

how can I set a instance of that entity ?

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Futures\CrmBundle\Entity\CasesReturn::setOrder() must be an instance of Futures\OrdersBundle\Entity\PurchaseOrder, integer given
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the entity from the entity Id, doing something like:

```
$order = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('FuturesCrmBundle:Order')
    ->find($cases['orderid']);
```

And then use this entity in the setOrder call:

```
$casesReturn->setOrder($order);
```